# Copy rows after using a filter and remember the row numbers in excel

Tags: excel, copy, rows

I am using a filter in my excel sheet. I have a row that contains 1 and 0. For example, I have 10 rows and row one contains 1 and row two contains 0 and tree contains 1 and so on. Now i filter on the 1's so it only shows row 1,3,5,7 and 9. I copy those ones and paste it into another sheet. The 1's are placed in the first five rows and not on row 1,3,5,7 and 9..

Does anyone know if there is a method to accomplish my needs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Filter the rows that you **DON'T NEED**
2. Clear their contents.
3. Disable filter.
4. Copy the entire table.

Comment: Used this, it worked but when I find a better way to do it, i am gonna use that one!